# Property 'navigationController' not found. UIView Interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a storyboard that handles all of my applications UI, apart from the header on each page which is handled by its own .xib file following this guide:

http://patientprogrammer.wordpress.com/2012/03/12/re-usable-subviews-in-ios/

Within my header .xib I have a button that I want to have when clicked load a view that is part of my story board.

I have tried:

```
- (IBAction)clicked:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    someViewController *storyViewController = [mainStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"someViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:storyViewController animated:YES];
}
```

However as my class uses the interface `UIView` controller `navigationController` is not found, what can I do to launch a view within the story board from my UIView. 
Or if there another interface I can use that will still let me have this as a subview.

Comment: Your view should notify the view controller that owns the view. A view should never do navigation

Answer (score 3):

> what can I do to launch a view within the story board from my UIView

This is bad. A view is a view. Its purpose is to show something to the user, not controlling the app.

`UIViewController` is where you will need to do this. The `navigationController` is a property on this class, not on `UIView`. Read [UIViewController class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more info.

Comment: Yes this makes sense, I currently have a class with the interface UIView as the guide I posted shows that adds its self as a subview. this is the owner of the headview.xib How would I also have a UIViewController for this view?

Comment: If you want to control the app flow, you need to have a `UIViewController` somewhere. You should create a class inheriting `UIViewController` and link it on your storyboard. You should let the `UIViewController` control what happens when you click on the button (i.e. your `clicked` method should be in your `UIViewController`.